# How to make a table multirow in differrent columns?

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to make this table

```
-------------------- 
|ColA | ColB | ColC  |
|-----|----- |------ |    
|Multi|-cell1|-cell4 |
|row1 |-cell2|-cell5 |
|     |-cell3|-cell6 |
|     |      |-cell7 |
|     |      |-cell8 | 
|--------------------|
|Multi|-cell9|-cell  |
|row12|-cell.|-cell5 |
|     |-cell.|-cell6 |
```

I am learning latex and I couldn't find a way to do this.
Help me please

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What did you try so far and what exactly did you not like about the output you got? What kind of contents will the individual table cells conatin? Do "- cell1", "- cell2", "-cell3"... represent items in a list, short/single line pieces of text or longer text that could span multiple lines? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? Maybe as a starting point?
`\multirowcell` (from the `makecell` package) is just a convenient way to use a multi-line item in a `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  ColA & ColB & ColC \\
  \hline
  \multirowcell{5}{Multi\\row1} & -cell1 & -cell4 \\
                          & -cell2 & -cell5 \\
                          & -cell3 & -cell6 \\
                          &        & -cell7 \\
                          &        & -cell8 \\
  \hline
  \multirowcell{3}{Multi\\row2} & -cell9 & -cell \\
                          & -cell. & -cell5 \\
                          & -cell. & -cell6 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly